# List all device information with Flutter on iOs

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, device

I am facing the project which should be as many other "boost cleaners". I'd appreciate any advise on this theme. As far as my research goes, I see, that it is quite more difficult to do in iOS, rather then Android. I don't hope for any good lib out there, and should probably do platform channels.

In general I need right now somehow get all device info - memory, battery, installed apps, cache, etc.

AS I've said, I had done a bit of research, and see the problem as stated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Libraries for it i don't think there is any library  which can support all info so you will have to use multiple libraries.
Just make sure library  should support all the platform you want to build you apps on.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/system_info_plus.      
https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info.     
https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus.      
https://pub.dev/packages/installed_apps (Only Android)
```